# Different behaviors with javascript's new Date(string)

Tags: javascript, date

A have a date on a string on the format yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss

I need to create a javascript Date object, so I do

`var d = new Date('2017-07-01T00:38:00')`

and the created object is

```
Sat Jul 01 2017 00:38:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
```

This is what I expect and what is happening on Chrome (v 59.0.3071.115 ) on my Desktop.

When I run the same code on my android phone, with Chrome version 51.0.2704.81 the result is

```
Sat Jul 01 2017 01:38:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
```

As you can see the hour is different due to my local timezone.

Is any of the above behaviors an expected one? Is it a matter of Chrome version? On my search I understood that the Date constructor with a string date produces unexpected results but can I rely on constant behavior independently of the browser?

---

EDIT

It's not a duplicate because on Firefox I have the same result that Chrome v59, the datetime is interpreted as local date and not UTC (that's what I want).

EDIT 2

On the "alleged" duplicated question the 'asker's' objective is that the `new Date()` treats the inserted date as UTC and make the necessary conversion to the users local time.
What I want is that the `new Date()` process the inserted date as **local date** without making any conversions. This is the behavior I'm getting on recent browsers (Chrome, Firefox) but no on old version of Chrome (in Android, v51).
So, if the users is on a timezone with +01:00 offset, if I make `new Date('2017-07-01T00:38:00')` the result should be `Sat Jul 01 2017 00:38:00 GMT+0100`

EDIT 3

Just checked that if I use the constructor `new Date(2017,06,01,0,38,0)` the date is interpreted as localdate (it shows `Sat Jul 01 2017 00:38:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)` on both versions of chrome... Is there any documentation that I can rely to be sure that will always interpreted as local date?

Comment: Try to add a `Z` at the end of the date/time string. As in `var d = new Date('2017-07-01T00:38:00Z')`.

Comment: It looks like a duplicate but it's on the same browser (chrome) but on different versions.

Comment: adding `Z` didn't solve the problem...

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in [ECMAScript 5.1 spec](https://bugs.ecmascript.org/show_bug.cgi?id=112).

Chrome implemented what the spec said literally, and replaced the behaviour of `Date` in Chrome 35 to one you should expect.

---

On the [previous specs](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/) (ECMAScript 5.1):

> `Z`   is the time zone offset specified as “Z” (for UTC) or either “+” or “-” followed by a time expression HH:mm
>
> [...]
>
> The value of an absent time zone offset is “Z”.

On the [current specs](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html) (fixed):

> When the time zone offset is absent, date-only forms are interpreted as a UTC time and date-time forms are interpreted as a local time.

Comment: according to your answer, on Chrome 51 this datetime should be interpreted as local time but its interpreted as UTC

Comment: Many would say that ed 5.1 got it right by being consistent with ISO 8601 and that the current spec is wrong. As it is now, it's consistent with ISO 8601 mostly but date-only forms are an exception.